# When water is heated in a vessel then what is the relation between the temperatures of water and vessel?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I came across a question where water was being heated in a calorimetry whose water equivalent was given. We were simply asked to find the energy required to bring the water to a certain temperature.

My question is that what is the relation Between the teeratures of the calorimeter and water because in the solution both the calorimeter and water were brought to the same final temperature. So does this mean that their temperatures are always the same?

Why can't the water and calorimeter reach different final temperatures?

Comment: What do you think would happen if they reached different temperatures?

Comment: They would want thermal equilibrium and would end up with the same temperature...thanks @ChetMiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly possible for the calorimeter and its content to have different temperatures during the process. However, when solving this sort of exercise, you usually assume that the final state is a state of thermodynamic equilibrium, so the final temperature must be common for both.

Since enthalpy is a state function, you only need to specify its initial and final values (index $c$ for the calorimeter, $w$ for water, $f$ for final and $i$ for initial):
$$\Delta H
=\Delta H_c+\Delta H_w
=C_c(T_f-T_{ci})+C_w(T_f-T_{wi})$$

So final temperature must be identical, but initial temperature can be different. Whether they are equal or not between the initial and final states doesn't matter in this equation.